# Create multiple subfolders same time chef

Tags: ruby, linux, chef-infra, chefdk

Not sure how I would use the array to create multiple 
sub folders of the Sales folder in chef.

```
sales = 'Sales'
salesfolders = %w{'NewClients', 'MarketingMaterial', 'SalesTools', 'ClientInformation'}


directory "#{directory}\\#{salesfolders}"
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  recursive true
  action :create
end '
```

}

Answer (score 5):

OK – there's a few things to look at. Firstly, `salesfolders` isn't currently a valid array. You'll want to define it either like this:

```
salesfolders = ['foo', 'bar']
```

or like this:

```
salesfolders = %w(foo bar)
```

The latter syntax is shorthand for an array of strings – it's the same as the first example, but with less syntactic sugar.

Once you've got a nicely formatted array, you need to iterate through that array and run some code for every item in it. In Ruby, this is achieved by calling `.each` on an array, like so:

```
salesfolders.each do |salesfolder|
  # do something with salesfolder
end
```

Note that there's a `salesfolder` variable set there, which will be different for each item of the array – if we look at our previous example, the first time that block of code is run it will be `foo`, the second `bar`, and so on.

With that in mind, if we want to run your Chef code for each salesfolder, we can do something like this:

```
salesfolders.each do |salesfolder|
  directory "/something/else/here/#{salesfolder}" do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0755'
    recursive true
    action :create
  end
end
```

For each salesfolder in our array, we'll run the `directory` block and create a new directory.